# How to select javascript tab using Selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, anchor

I'm trying to achieve a tab of `Send sms`, Hope this image will help you, what i'm looking for. Please [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhDJP.png).

So, here is source code:

```
<li id="sendSMS" class="active">
   <a href="javascript:loadSMSPage('sendSMS');">Send SMS</a>
</li>
```

Now, I tried this source code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send SMS")).click();
```

Unfortunately, This is *NOT* working :(

*Please help, Surely help would be appreciated!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually rely on `linkText` that much Try using `xpath` with text based search

also, try this

```
//li[@id='sendSMS']/a

By byXpath = By.xpath("//a[.='Send SMS']");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath);
myDynamicElement.click();
```

**EDIT:** 
Added `explicit` wait

Comment: I tried everything dude.. it says: `Unable to locate a node using //a[.='Send SMS']`